# Parameters only in mondrian or in sql too in pentaho

Tags: sql, parameters, mdx, pentaho

Good morning, I have a question I try to pass some parameters to an sql query of the pentaho cde and I get an error (the query does not show anything). The examples that I look on the internet use MDX on Mondrian. Is it mandatory to create a schema in Mondrian and use MDX? Thank you very much

Comment: yes it is mandatory to create a schema in Mondrian and use MDX

Comment: Thanks, how can i create a schema in mondrian? or can you give me any tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find below description  from pentaho docs

1. To create a new Mondrian schema, click the New button, or go to the
   File menu, then select New, then Schema. A new schema sub-window
   will appear. Resize it to fit your preference.
2. It's easier to visualize your physical data model if you have it in
   front of you. Turn on the JDBC Explorer from the New section of the
   File menu and position it according to your preference. If you have
   a third-party database visualization tool that you are more familiar
   with, use that instead. The JDBC Explorer is not interactive; it
   only shows the table structure of your data source so that you can
   see at a glance what the names of the columns and rows in it.
3. Typically your first action when creating a schema is to add a cube.
   Right-click the Schema icon in the schema window, then select Add
   cube from the context menu. Alternatively you can click the New Cube
   button in the toolbar. A new default cube will show up in your
   schema.
4. Add a table by clicking the New Table button, or by right-clicking
   your cube, then selecting Add Table. This will be your fact table.
   Alternatively you can select View or Inline Table if these are the
   data types you need for your fact table.
5. Click the Table entry in the name field of your new table, and
   select or type in the name of the table in your physical model that
   you want to use for this cube's fact table.
6. Add a dimension by right-clicking the cube, then selecting Add
   Dimension, or by clicking the New Dimension button.
7. When you add a dimension, a new hierarchy is automatically created
   for it. To configure the hierarchy, expand the dimension by clicking
   the lever icon on the left side of the dimension's tree entry, then
   click on New Hierarchy 0. Choose a primaryKey or primaryKey Table.
8. Add a table to the hierarchy by right-clicking the hierarchy, then
   selecting Add Table from the context menu.
9. Add a level to the hierarchy by right-clicking the hierarchy, then
   selecting Add Level from the context menu.
10. Add a member property to the level by right-clicking the level,
     then selecting Add Property from the context menu.
11. Add a measure to the cube by right-clicking the cube and selecting
     Add Measure from the context menu.
12. Choose a column that you want to provide values for, then select an
     aggregator to determine how the values should be calculated.

    These instructions have shown you how to use Schema Workbench's
     interface to add and configure basic Mondrian schema elements.

[pentaho docs](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.3/0N0/020/070/020)

Comment: Thanks, but i click in file and only appear to create a new sayku Analytics, cde dashboard, jpivot view and data source. i have to click in data source? Sorry but i'm new in pentaho

Comment: sayku analytics is 3rd party tools which used for showing data from schema workbench

Comment: and where is de button to create a new mondrian schema? because i only watch this 4 buttons

Comment: Yes i have schema workbench and now i'm working with schema workbench. When i click in connection and click in test it give me the next error:Error connecting to database [JIRA] :org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database
Driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver' could not be found, make sure the 'Oracle' driver (jar file) is installed.
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver....but in cde dashboard when i create a datasource all is ok. i don't know what is happen

Comment: @ilanas a lot of tutorial available of youtube about connectiona and schema creation use those materials btw it this post helps you please accept answer